# Is echo atomic when writing single lines

Tags: bash, scripting, concurrency

I am currently trying to get a script to write output from other started commands correctly into a log file. The script will write it's own messages to the log file using echo and there is a method to which I can pipe the lines from the other program.

The main problem is, that the program which produces the output is started in the background, so my function that does the read may write concurently to the logfile. Could this be a problem? Echo always only writes a single line, so it should not be to hard to ensure atomicity. However I have looked in google and I have found no way to make sure it actually is atomic.

Here is the current script:

```
LOG_FILE=/path/to/logfile

write_log() {
  echo "$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S);$1" >> ${LOG_FILE}
}

write_output() {
  while read data; do
    write_log "Message from SUB process: [ $data ]"
  done
}

write_log "Script started"
# do some stuff
call_complicated_program 2>&1 | write_output &
SUB_PID=$!
#do some more stuff
write_log "Script exiting"
wait $SUB_PID
```

As you can see, the script might write both on it's own as well as because of redirected output. Could this cause havok in the file?

Comment: I don't think bash is the right tool for this job. I'd recommend something more powerful (perl, python, ruby..)

Comment: Incidentally, if you have a *lot* of data going into this log then you might find that continually opening and closing the log file is a bad idea. You can permanently open a file with `exec 3>>${LOG_FILE}` and then write to it any time you like with `echo whatever >&3`. You can close the file with `exec 3>&-`, but that'll happen when the script exits anyway. The only problem is you have to manually choose a number for each file you open, and 0, 1 and 2 are already taken.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`echo`  just a simple wrapper around `write` (this is a simplification; see edit below for the gory details), so to determine if echo is atomic, it's useful to look up write. From the [single UNIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/write.html):

> Atomic/non-atomic: A write is atomic if the whole amount written in one operation is not interleaved with data from any other process. This is useful when there are multiple writers sending data to a single reader. Applications need to know how large a write request can be expected to be performed atomically.This maximum is called {PIPE_BUF}. Thisvolume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 does not say whether write requests for more than {PIPE_BUF} bytes are atomic, but requires that writes of {PIPE_BUF}or fewer bytes shall be atomic.

You can check `PIPE_BUF` on your system with a simple C program. If you're just printing a single line of output, that is not ridiculously long, it should be atomic.

Here is a simple program to check the value of `PIPE_BUF`:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", PIPE_BUF);

  return 0;
}
```

On Mac OS X, that gives me 512 (the [minimum allowed value](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/limits.h.html) for `PIPE_BUF`). On Linux, I get 4096. So if your lines are fairly long, make sure you check it on the system in question.

**edit to add**: I decided to check [the implementation of `echo`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/echo.def) in Bash, to confirm that it will print atomically. It turns out, `echo` uses `putchar` or `printf` depending on whether you use the `-e` option. These are buffered stdio operations, which means that they fill up a buffer, and actually write it out only when a newline is reached (in line-buffered mode), the buffer is filled (in block-buffered mode), or you explicitly flush the output with `fflush`. By default, a stream will be in line buffered mode if it is an interactive terminal, and block buffered mode if it is any other file. Bash never sets the buffering type, so for your log file, it should default to block buffering mode. At then [end of the `echo` builtin](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/echo.def#n197), Bash [calls `fflush`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/common.c#n334) to flush the output stream. Thus, the output will always be flushed at the end of `echo`, but may be flushed earlier if it doesn't fit into the buffer.

The size of the buffer used may be `BUFSIZ`, though it may be different; `BUFSIZ` is the default size if you set the buffer explicitly using `setbuf`, but there's no portable way to determine the actual the size of your buffer. There are also no portable guidelines for what `BUFSIZ` is, but when I tested it on Mac OS X and Linux, it was twice the size of `PIPE_BUF`.

What does this all mean? Since the output of `echo` is all buffered, it won't actually call the `write` until the buffer is filled or `fflush` is called. At that point, the output should be written, and the atomicity guarantee I mentioned above should apply. If the stdout buffer size is larger than `PIPE_BUF`, then `PIPE_BUF` will be the smallest atomic unit that can be written out. If `PIPE_BUF` is larger than the stdout buffer size, then the stream will write the buffer out when the buffer fills up.

So, `echo` is only guaranteed to atomically write sequences shorter than the smaller of `PIPE_BUF` and the size of the stdout buffer, which is most likely `BUFSIZ`. On most systems, `BUFSIZ` is larger that `PIPE_BUF`.

**tl;dr**: `echo` will atomically output lines, as long as those lines are short enough. On modern systems, you're probably safe up to 512 bytes, but it's not possible to determine the limit portably.

Comment: Here's a table of observed `PIPE_BUF` values on common Unix systems: http://ar.to/notes/posix#pipe-buf

Comment: In my tests using bash 4 and 5, `echo` does not write its entire message atomically if the message contains newline (`\n`) characters. It always writes each line separately regardless of whether the output is a terminal or not.
This can be verified by running:
`strace -e trace=write bash -c "echo 'hello"$'\n'"world'" | cat > /dev/null
write(1, "hello\n", 6)                  = 6
write(1, "world\n", 6)                  = 6
+++ exited with 0 +++
`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the approach [from user:pizza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9937496/117471) and could not get it to work like the answer [from user:Brian Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9927415/117471). Let me know if I am doing something work and I'll update the answer. (And yes this is an answer because I'm actually giving a complete working demo.)

## basic concurrency

This just illustrates the problem

```
$ for n in {1..5}; do (curl -svo /dev/null example.com 2>&1 &) done | grep GET
> GET / HTTP/1.1
>>  GET / HTTP/1.1
GET / HTTP/1.1
>>>  GET / HTTP/1.1
>>GET / HTTP/1.1
```

## using echo on each line of output

This solves the problem using [Brian Campbell's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9927415/117471). (Note that the length of the line for which this works is limited.)

```
$ for n in {1..5}; do (curl -svo /dev/null example.com 2>&1 | while read; do echo "${REPLY}"; done &) done | grep GET
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
```

## redirecting the for loop to append to stdout

Instinct should tell you that this is not going to work because it redirects after all the the output of the forked curls have been merged.

```
$ for n in {1..5}; do (curl -svo /dev/null example.com 2>&1 &) done >> /dev/stdout | grep GET
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
>> >GET / HTTP/1.1
 >  GET / HTTP/1.1
 GET / HTTP/1.1
```

## redirecting each curl to append to stdout

I suspect this failure is do to the fact that the entire content of each curl is being redirected and the size is greater than what the kernel is willing to block for. I have not taken the time to confirm that, but what Brian Campbell did share seems to support it.

```
$ for n in {1..5}; do (curl -svo /dev/null example.com >>/dev/stdout 2>&1 &) done | grep GET
>>  GET / HTTP/1.1
GET / HTTP/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
GET / HTTP/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no involuntary file locking, but the >> operator is safe, the > operator is unsafe. So your practice is safe to do.