# Parallel writing to a file from multiple processes by using echo

Tags: linux, bash, file-locking

I have written a function in our ERP-System which writes a log to a file on the server by simply "echoing" it to the logfile.

```
echo "SOME LOGDATA" >> /users/erp/log/LOGMSG
```

Every time a user triggers a specific event, the LOG function is called.

**What would happen if 2 users trigger the LOG event exactly at the same time?**

Does "echo" take care of file locking?
In my opinion it has to be the linux kernel or the bash who has to takes care, that a file is not written by 2 command line instructions simultaneously.

I wrote a testcase to force this condition (some 1000 LOG calls within one second) and it seems that my thoughts are right but I can not be really sure, that these calls are executed at the same time on the bash.

Comment: Any reason not to use [logger](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9927415/2214693), echo is guaranteed to be atomic only when writing sequences shorter than the smaller of `PIPE_BUF` and the size of the stdout buffer (which is most likely `BUFSIZ`).

For longer sequences, you need to locking. Use can use `lockfile-create` and `lockfile-check`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GNU Parallel as a mutex/semaphore ensuring that only one `echo` runs at a time like this:

```
sem --id mysem echo "System crashed"  >> log.txt
```

GNU Parallel is installed on most Linux distros, and is readily available for OSX via `homebrew`.

You can test the idea by starting a loop in each of two, or more, terminals and having each one do this:

```
for i in {1..100}; do sem --id mysem echo hi >> log ; done
```

and at the end you will see there are exactly 100 lines per terminal in your log.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful not to reinvent the wheel, in *nix systems there is [syslog](http://syslog.org) to handle logging in a proper way. The problem with `echo` to a file is that you can enforce mutual exclusion but the hardest part would be to handle serialization, the fact that one `echo` writes before another does not mean that the logged operation actually executed first (nor in parallel).

Comment: I know of syslog. But as far as I know it logs all messages to /var/log/message which is not a proper place for my logs.

Comment: Actually you can configure it to log anywhere you want based on process name

Comment: Didn't know that it can be configured. THX for that. Can you do logging as a regular user without being root or use sudo?