# How to share a variable between scripts that run in parallel?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, concurrency

I would like to run two bash scripts simultaneously executed by a parent script that exports a variable with read and write privileges between all these scripts. Let's say I have 3 scripts: ***`parent.sh`***, ***`children1.sh`***, ***`children2.sh`***. From ***`parent.sh`*** I am exporting a `SOME_VAR` variable and executing `./children1.sh & children2sh` simultaneously. Then in ***`children1.sh`*** and  ***`children2.sh`*** I am performing some operation. In addition, we can see ***`children2.sh`*** is overriding `SOME_VAR` variable with value `20`. I would like to have this change to be reflected in ***`parent.sh`***. So, for example, let's say I have such scripts:

***`parent.sh`***

```bash
#!/bin/bash
SOME_VAR=100
export SOME_VAR
bash ./children1.sh & ./children2.sh
echo "New SOME_VAR value: $SOME_VAR"
```

***`children1.sh`***

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..3}
do
   echo "### FIRST PROCESS  $i"
done
```

***`children2.sh`***

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..3}
do
   echo "### SECOND PROCESS  $i"
done
SOME_VAR=20
```

Now if I execute `bash ./parent.sh` I get such output:

```
### SECOND PROCESS  1 
### FIRST PROCESS  1 
### SECOND PROCESS  2 
### FIRST PROCESS  2 
### SECOND PROCESS  3 
### FIRST PROCESS  3 
New SOME_VAR value: 100
```

Unfortunately, it looks like that ***`children2.sh`*** operation was not reflected back to ***`parent.sh`*** and `SOME_VAR` variable is still equal to `100` instead of `20`. I came up with the idea that each script can create a file and write its output to this file. Later, these files can be read by the parent script after the children's scripts finish their work. This solution sounds a bit hacky to me. I am not a `bash` expert, so maybe someone can help me with a more sufficient solution.

There is one requirement: **You can NOT use any 3rd party libraries/tools like for example, GNU Parallel**

Comment: Linux does not support the idea of exported variables (i.e. environment variables) to be **shared** between two processes. Environment variables are **inherited** from parent to child, but once the child process has started, the two insances of the variables are independent. Admittedly, the concept of have "shared variables" could be an interesting synchronization tool, but you have to live with what you got. Think of having shared _data_  between processes. This could be for instance  implemented by a database, a file or shared memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you said in the comments below about not really needing all of your scripts to share a variable but instead just needing children running in the background to be able to each return a value to the parent, something like this might be best:

```
$ cat parent.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo=1000
bar=999

run_children() {
    local -A children
    local -a pids
    local var

    children[foo]=./child1.sh
    children[bar]=./child2.sh

    for var in "${!children[@]}"; do
        printf '%s\n%s\0' "$var" "$( "${children[$var]}" )" &
        pids+=( $! )
    done

    wait "${pids[@]}"
}

while read -r -d '' var val; do
    printf -v "$var" '%s' "$val"
done < <( run_children )

printf 'foo=%s\n' "$foo"
printf 'bar=%s\n' "$bar"
```

```
$ cat child1.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in {1..3}
do
   echo "### FIRST PROCESS  $i" >&2
   sleep 2
done

printf "now is the winter\nof our discontent\n"
```

```
$ cat child2.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in {1..3}
do
   echo "### SECOND PROCESS  $i" >&2
   sleep 1
done

printf 'wee, sleekit, cowrin\ntimrous beastie\n'
```

```
$ ./parent.sh
### FIRST PROCESS  1
### SECOND PROCESS  1
### SECOND PROCESS  2
### FIRST PROCESS  2
### SECOND PROCESS  3
### FIRST PROCESS  3
foo=now is the winter
of our discontent
bar=wee, sleekit, cowrin
timrous beastie
```

I had the children output multi-line string values just to show the approach works for that case as well as the desired single-number output case.

I gave `child1` a longer `sleep` interval between iterations than `child2` to show that the script waits for all processes to end before reading their output and isn't affected by the order they run in.

Note in all of the above that the children scripts know nothing about the parent variables, thereby maintaining loose coupling between them. If any of the children need to use the value of `foo` or `bar` as initially set in the parent then, unless there's some reason we don't know about yet, I'd recommend passing the value as an argument to keep that loose coupling rather than exporting it in the parent and then referencing the variable in a child as that would undesirably and unnecessarily create tight coupling.

---

Original Answer:

A child process cannot change the value of a variable in a parent process. `export` lets the child process see the value of the variable and change it within itself, not modify it's value back in the parent.

You can do:

```
var=$( child )
```

to set the value in the parent to a string the child prints, or:

```
child
var=$?
```

to set the value in the parent to an integer exit status from the child, or

```
. child
```

to make the child run in the same process and so it's variables and the parents variables co-mingle but none of those would let you share a variable between child processes running in the background - for that you need a file:

```
child1:
    echo 10 > "$TMP"

child2:
    echo 20 > "$TMP"

parent:
    export TMP=$(mktemp)
    echo 100 > "$TMP"
    child1 &
    child2 &
    sleep 5    # or "wait" or similar
    IFS= read -r val < "$TMP"
    echo "$val"
```

but then you probably should introduce some locking mechanism around the file (see [@CharlesDuffy's answer at is-writing-to-a-unix-file-through-shell-script-is-synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34445231/1745001) and [the `flock` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock)) in case different processes are trying to read/write it simultaneously if whatever you're doing with it isn't atomic.

`flock` is available on most systems but it's not POSIX so if it's not available to you due to your requirement that "You can NOT use any 3rd party libraries/tools" then obviously you'd have to come up with some other way to do that part.

Comment: In my case I do not need to worry about locking as children1 is not going to modify variables of children2 and vice-versa. Simply children1 and children2 will perform some operations and set flag based on the result then parent process will get the outputs and do sth based on the result, so I think locking is not needed, or I am mistaken?
> btw I haven't know about `mktemp` quite usefull command, thx

Comment: You still need locking so parent isn't trying to read the value while either child is writing it. How will the child set a flag if not by the same method as it's setting the value and then you've just shifted the problem from setting the value to setting the flag? Having said that, it'll PROBABLY be OK either way as you'll PROBABLY be doing an atomic write/read but just read the documentation for whatever you're using to write/read the values to make sure.

Comment: Yes, but my parents will wait until all job is done by children's scripts, so I think such a situation should not happen.

Comment: I see, then yes you should be fine as long as both children don't try to write to/read from the same file.

Comment: What you described in your comments is different from needing "a variable with read and write privileges between all these scripts" as stated in your question so I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> You can NOT use any 3rd party libraries/tools like for example, GNU Parallel

Are you aware, that you can export GNU Parallel using `parallel --embed`? This way you do not need to install GNU Parallel on the target system: It will not be treated as a 3rd party tool, but be part of your shell script.

If that is acceptable, you can use `parset`.

On the development system do:

```
parallel --embed > myscript.sh
```

Append to `myscript.sh`:

```
child1() {
  childvar1=value1
  echo "$childvar1";
}
child2() {
  childvar2=value2
  echo "$childvar2";
}
export -f child1 child2

parset var1,var2 ::: child1 child2

# Or if you prefer scripts over functions:
parset var1,var2 ::: child1.sh child2.sh

echo "$var1"
echo "$var2"
```

Now move it to the system without GNU Parallel.